# pdfkit not working when serving flask app with gunicorn and nginx

Tags: python, nginx, flask, gunicorn, pdfkit

On the development server I can create a pdf and send this through to the end user by using pdfkit

My view that returns the pdf

```
@changesBP.route('/pdf', methods=['GET'])
def pdfView():
    if not 'dataDict' in session:
        flash('Du skal uploade regneark for at kunne fortsætte på siden')
        return redirect(url_for('indexBP.indexView'))

    balanceChangelist = session['balanceGruppeChanges']
    balanceGrupper = balanceData(data = session['dataDict'])
    balanceListe = session['balanceListe']
    resultatChangelist = session['resultatGruppeChanges']
    resultatGrupper = resultatData(data = session['dataDict'])
    resultatListe = session['resultatListe']

    aendingsLister = []

    for bc in balanceChangelist:
        for c in bc['changes']:
            if c['list'] not in aendingsLister:
                aendingsLister.append(c['list'])

    for rc in resultatChangelist:
        for c in rc['changes']:
            if c['list'] not in aendingsLister:
                aendingsLister.append(c['list'])

    options = {
        'page-size': 'Letter',
        'margin-top': '0.75in',
        'margin-right': '0.75in',
        'margin-bottom': '0.75in',
        'margin-left': '0.75in',
        'encoding': "UTF-8",
        'no-outline': None,
        'quiet': ''
    }

    html = render_template('pdfTemplate.html', balanceChangelist = balanceChangelist, 
                                           balanceGrupper = balanceGrupper,
                                           balanceListe = balanceListe,
                                           resultatChangelist = resultatChangelist,
                                           resultatGrupper = resultatGrupper,
                                           resultatListe = resultatListe,
                                           aendingsLister = aendingsLister)

    out_File = BytesIO()
    out_File.write(pdfkit.from_string(html, False, options=options))
    out_File.seek(0)
    return send_file(out_File, 
                     attachment_filename='out.pdf',
                     as_attachment=True, 
                     mimetype="application/pdf")
```

When serving the app through gunicorn and Nginx following [this guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-gunicorn-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-16-04) I get a bad gateway error when accessing the pdf view.

I could use a bit of help on the error log that states the following

> 2017/12/13 10:04:39 [error] 28047#28047: *78 upstream prematurely
>   closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client:
>   10.2.20.180, server: 10.8.0.12, request: "GET /pdf HTTP/1.1", upstream: http://unix:/home/hepo/segesdupont/segesdupont.sock:/pdf",
>   host: "10.8.0.12", referrer: "http://10.8.0.12/changes"

Any ideas?

Comment: The app server is probably timing out. PDF rendering can be slow. (Check the gunicorn config for the timeout settings -- [the default is 30s](http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/0.17.2/configure.html#timeout).) Usually you want to kick off a background job in the page request and then let the user know where to find the file once the job is complete and the PDF is ready.

Comment: Hmm the pdf does not take much more than 1 sec to render on my dev system, so I hadn't thought about timeout issues. will look into it though. Untill then I solved the issue by using client side jsPDF and HTML2canvas

Comment: Why did you decide to use `send_file` instead of just returning the bytes?

Comment: Didn't know that was an option to be honest :)

Comment: I'm also facing the same issue. looking for a solution, @HenrikPoulsen did you find any solution or workaround

Answer (score 0):

The internal error for this problem is "UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xea' in position 193: ordinal not in range(128)".

You can solve this just by removing any special characters from the html you are using to generate the pdf. Use the á instead of á.

Comment: The same tip is also applied for name.of the generated pdf file.

Answer (score 0):

**Diagnostic elements:**

- Your file is correctly generated when you are on your development server.
- When you're behind nginx, it does not work anymore.
- Your file contains accented characters.

**Possible problem:**
 a bad `locale` configuration on the server.

**The solution:**

**STEP 1:** Try to watch your `locales`. In your terminal type:

```
$ locale  //DISPLAYING CURRENT SETTINGS 
$ locale -a  //DISPLAYING AVAILABLE LOCALES
```

If your locales are well defined, I guess in the results you get you will have a line like `LANG=de_DE.UTF-8` for sytems in Germanic languages... otherwise you need [to reconfigure your locales](https://www.thomas-krenn.com/en/wiki/Configure_Locales_in_Ubuntu).

**STEP 2:** check your `locales` via your python interpreter:

```
>>> import locale
>>> locale.getlocale()
>>> locale.getdefaultlocale()
```

These commands are supposed to inform you about the state of your `locale` in the context of python. You must also look at the state of the `locale` in the specific context of your application.

After checking and eventualy correcting, You have to adjust the scripts you use to serve your application.

For example, I use `supervisor` to manage my applications served by **Nginx + Gunicorn**. This is what my configuration file looks like:

```
[progam:myapp]
environment=LANG="fr_FR.UTF-8"
// OTHERS COMMANDS...
```

**Conclusion**:

Add the line `environment=LANG="de_DE.UTF-8"` to your configuration scripts (`init.d`, etc.). or any configuration that supports your language; probably the configuration used by default by your `locale system`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the html template which you are converting, does not contain any links generated by a templating engine. wkhtmltopdf needs absolute paths. This is a pitfall when deploying to a production server.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32536205)